# Are laboratory techniques and safety on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I just stumbled upon a new proposal at Area51:

> ### [Laboratory Techniques and Safety](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64768/laboratory-techniques-and-safety)
>
> Proposed Q&A site for researchers, scientists, and students at all levels in all fields of science interested in learning or improving their skills in the lab related to safely conducting experiments and handling equipment.

As I've been dabbling in the chemistry field as I was a teenager, something tells me that "lab safety" and co. are pretty much related to "practical chemistry"; no matter if we're talking about a hobby-lab at home, or a full-fledged professional chemistry laboratory.

Yet, I don't want to flag that Area51 proposal by pointing to Chemistry.SE if it's not on-topic here… which is why I would like to know: *Are "laboratory techniques and safety" on-topic here at Chemistry.SE?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions regarding experimental techniques and safety are most welcomed on Chemistry.SE under the tags [experimental-technique](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experimental-technique) and [safety](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety).

Any Biology lab techniques questions on that new proposal would likely be on-topic on Biology.SE.

Comment: And likely the equivalent questions for physics would likely be on-topic on Physics.SE.